# Fail in java eclipse with java.awt.Graphics (bug?)

Tags: java, swing

I recently tried to programm a moving Nyancat, which can shoot lazers by pressing the left mouse button. But whenever i press the Button the Picture of the Cat starts to bug. Help me please. Here is the Main part of the Code:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {

    Graphics pen = contentPane.getGraphics();
    int w = contentPane.getWidth();
    int h = contentPane.getHeight();
    if(arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
        System.out.println("right");
        left = false;
        right = true;
        up = false;
        down = false;
        pen.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        pen.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
    }
if(arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){
if(start == false){

    pen.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    pen.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
        timer.start();
        start = true;
    }
}
if(arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
System.out.println("left");
left = true;
right = false;
up = false;
down = false;
pen.setColor(Color.BLACK);
pen.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);

}
if(arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
System.out.println("up");
left =false;
right = false;
up = true;
down = false;
pen.setColor(Color.BLACK);
pen.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);

}
if(arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
System.out.println("down");
left = false;
right = false;
up = false;
down =true;
pen.setColor(Color.BLACK);
pen.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);

}

}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {


}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {


}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

    Graphics pen = contentPane.getGraphics();
    int w = contentPane.getWidth();
    int h = contentPane.getHeight();

    if(right == true){
        x = x+1;


        pen.drawImage(right_cat, x, y, d, d/2+d/4,this);
    }
    if(left == true){
        x = x-1;

        pen.drawImage(left_cat, x, y, d, d/2+d/4,this);
    }
    if(up == true){
        y = y-1;

        pen.drawImage(up_cat, x, y,  d/2+d/4, d,this);
    }
    if(down == true){
        y = y+1;

        pen.drawImage(down_cat, x, y,  d/2+d/4, d,this);
    }
    if(fire == true){
          wxx = x;
          wyy = y;
          if(right == true){
          pen.setColor(Color.CYAN);
          pen.drawLine(x+d, y+(( d/2+d/4)/2), wx, wy);
          fire = false;
          firetimer = true;
          }
          if(left = true){
              pen.setColor(Color.CYAN);
              pen.drawLine(x, y+(( d/2+d/4)/2), wx, wy);
              fire = false;
              firetimer = true;
          }
          if(down == true){
              pen.setColor(Color.CYAN);
              pen.drawLine(x+(( d/2+d/4)/2), y+d, wx, wy);
              fire = false;
              firetimer = true;
          }
          if(up== true){
              pen.setColor(Color.CYAN);
              pen.drawLine(x+(( d/2+d/4)/2), y, wx, wy);
              fire = false;
              firetimer = true;
          }

      }
      if(firetimer == true ){
          i ++;
      }
    if(i >=20){
        pen.setColor(Color.BLACK);
         pen.drawLine(wxx+d, wyy+(( d/2+d/4)/2), wx, wy);
         firetimer = false;
         i = 0;
    }



}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
    if(firetimer == false){
    wx = arg0.getX();
    wy = arg0.getY();
    fire = true;
    }

}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Comment: `contentPane.getGraphics();` be the first point of concern, take a look at [Painting in Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details on how painting should be done

Comment: You'll probably also want to have a look at [How to use key bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Comment: i didnt include the Keybinding in the code i showed here, the keys and the java.awt.Graphics work perfect, its just the click of the Mouse who causes the "bug". i think it is a bug

Comment: It's not a bug, you're just not using the api the it's suppose to be used, read the links and don't use getGraphics, this is not hie custom painting works